# Confused why a test in section 5.3 should fail

Tags: testing, contacts, railstutorial.org

In the Rails Tutorial, section 5.3 (Layout links) we add some tests for the Contact page:

```
describe "Contact page" do

  it "should have the content 'Contact'" do
    visit '/static_pages/contact'
    expect(page).to have_content('Contact')
  end

  it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
    visit '/static_pages/contact'
    expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
  end
end
```

After which we comment out the Contact link in the footer code:

```
<li><%#= link_to "Contact", '#' %></li>
```

According to the text, "To ensure that both of the tests in Listing 5.17 fail, we need to comment out the “Contact” link in the footer", but that doesn't make sense to me. There is no test for the Contact link, only tests that the Contact page has valid title and content. If the Contact page is properly defined the tests should still pass whether there's a link in the footer or not.

Or am I missing something here? It behaves as I expect it to, but I don't want to just continue on and miss something I should be understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't comment out the link, the first test will pass before we create our Contact page. That's because RSpec will search for the word "Contact" anywhere on the page (that's how 'have_content' works), so it will find it in the footer, which means the first test will pass thanks to our generic footer, not thanks to us actually creating a Contact page.

Comment: Ah I see. If I hadn't created the Contact page in a previous section it would have failed. It would be clearer if the text pointed out that it wouldn't fail if the Contact page exists (since an earlier section suggested it as an exercise), but I'll plead Monday brainfart on this one. :)  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, right, forgot there was an exercise on that! Yes, after commenting out that line, both tests would have failed if you hadn't done the exercise :)